# How can I fix scanner artifacts from Brother DS-640?

Tags: artifacts, scanner

I've been scanning a lot of documents using a Brother DS-640 and it has started showing odd pixelation artifacts. (See below.) Is it time for a new scanner or is this something I can fix?

[image]

Comment: Does poster have any repetitive texture?

Comment: This kind of things happens because the sampling periodicity (pixels on the sensor) get close to a periodic pattern on the image (half-toning). Scanner software foten have settings to mitigate this. Otherwise you can try to change the ratio between the two by canting the image in the scanner (and then straightening it in post). Another solution is to make several scans with some random shift of the source, stack and align them, and set the top ones to `Lighten only`.

Comment: While scanning and digital imaging are part of photography, scanning documents on a flatbed scanner is not photography - therefore your question is a bad fit for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question isn't about photography.

Comment: @osullic This isn't a photo there but scanning a photo could lead to same artifacts with very high probability.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Photos don't show the same patterns. The image doesn't appear to be printed with "Ben Day dots". At least, they aren't visible to my naked eye.

Comment: @JohnnyRollerfeet is the surface finish also uniform?